# View Components and Ajax Server Side Validations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

My app requires the ability to send emails on multiple views. I'm trying to use a View Component so I can reuse my logic multiple places. When the user clicks the Send button I don't want to refresh the entire view...I want to validate the form and display any model errors, else send the email.

The setup below works fine for Client Side validation, but I'm not sure how to bring back the model errors server side and display them in the view. Any help is appreciated.

**Default.cshtml** (View Component - using jquery-ajax-unobtrusive)

```
@model EmailViewModel   
<div id="Email">
    <div class="row section-buffer">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <span class="section-header">Email</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <form id="EmailForm"
          method="post"
          class="form-horizontal"
          asp-controller="Email"
          asp-action="Send"
          data-ajax="true"
          data-ajax-method="POST"
          data-ajax-success="sendEmailSuccess"
          data-ajax-failure="sendEmailFailure(xhr, status, error)"
          data-ajax-update="Email">

        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label class="description-label col-sm-3" asp-for="From"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="From" />
                <span asp-validation-for="From" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- remaining fields omitted -->
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**EmailViewModel**

```
public class EmailViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string From{ get; set; }
    //remaining properties omitted
}
```

**EmailController**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/email/send")]
public ActionResult Send(EmailViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //how do return my model errors back to my View Component?
    }
    else
    {
        //do send logic here
        return Content("Success");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep error in ViewBag

```
@model EmailViewModel   
<div id="Email">
    <div class="row section-buffer">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <span class="section-header">Email</span>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div>@ViewBag.Error</div>
    <hr />
    <form id="EmailForm"
          method="post"
          class="form-horizontal"
          asp-controller="Email"
          asp-action="Send"
          data-ajax="true"
          data-ajax-method="POST"
          data-ajax-success="sendEmailSuccess"
          data-ajax-failure="sendEmailFailure(xhr, status, error)"
          data-ajax-update="Email">

        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <label class="description-label col-sm-3" asp-for="From"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="From" />
                <span asp-validation-for="From" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- remaining fields omitted -->
        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Return View with error

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/email/send")]
public ActionResult Send(EmailViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //how do return my model errors back to my View Component?
         return Content(string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values
                                    .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)));
       //in send email success javascript method handle this message and show.

    }
    else
    {
        //do send logic here
        return Content("Success");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to return a message that I generate. I want to return the model validations. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: I have just kept a sample message, you can return whatever you need

Comment: `return View()` doesn't work because Send.cshtml doesn't exist. My View Component view is named Default.cshtml (convention) and exists in Shared/Components/Email.

Comment: @RyanBuening then just return content and handle it in the javascript success method sendEmailSuccess